# cannot access ajax data sent on the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, backbone.js

I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/) to make an events calendar-it utilizes backbone and the fullcalendar jquery plugin.

Backbone is responsible for sending to the server(via ajax) event details(start date,end date,title).Here is an image [image: snapshot] of what is sent to the server.

It is taken by the network panel(headers tab) of Chrome Dev Tools. I would expect that with the following line of code I would access the title of the event:

```
$title=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

But I cannot, I do not understand why this happens. backbone sends JSON to server via the POST method. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that it's being sent via POST? To humor me, please check the GET table.

Otherwise - do you know if there are any redirects (.htaccess / header) in your code? ($_POST data won't be included in these)

Comment: Decode the JSON with `json_decode($_POST['title']);`

Comment: Your data is being sent as the body of the request rather than as post parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a problem with parsing json data,  because it expects the posted data to be in a Querystring format `(key=value&key1=value1)`.try using this:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Am I going to use for parameter of the above function the php page where the ajax data is sent?I do not quite understand how am I going to get the title of the event with the above function.

Comment: I thought the above was an example-I will just copy paste

Comment: what gets returned to the contents variable though?How Will I able to access title?I will do testing my own but I am asking also.

Comment: You'll get a json string and then you can use json_decode to get an actual json object.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a JSON dictionary in the request body. Use [http_get_request_body](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) in PHP to obtain the full JSON string, then [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) it.

Comment: There is one question I wish to make regarding the above.When we use the jquery function  $.ajax from where the json gets sent.Is in it also the request body?